# Saving Location of Scraped Image to DB - Node/MEAN

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongoose, mean, multer

After scraping an image I'm able to download to a folder using request. I would like to pass along the location of this image to my Mongoose collection.

In the callback I think there should be a way to save the location so I can pass this along when saving my model object.

```
exports.createLook = function(req, res) {
  var url = req.body.image;
  var randomizer = '123456';

  var download = function(url, filename, callback) {

    request(url)
      .pipe(fs.createWriteStream(filename))
      .on('close', callback);
  };

  download(url, '../client/assets/images/' + randomizer + '.jpg', function() {
    console.log('done');
    // do something?
  });

   // now get model details to save
   var newLook = new Look();
   newLook.title = req.body.title;
   newLook.image =       // image location

   newLook.save(function(err, look) {
     if(err) return res.send(500);
  } else {
    res.send(item);
  }
}
```

Comment: not sure if I understand you. Looking at your code you could just set  `newLook.image =  "../client/assets/images/' + randomizer + '.jpg"`

Comment: I'm going to change randomizer to something that creates a random string.   So first I download and save the image to my folder, then I save it to my model, so randomizer will change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that 'randomizer' will be generated I would do:

```
exports.createLook = function(req, res) {
  var url = req.body.image;
  var randomizer = getSomthingRandom();

  var download = function(url, filename, callback) {

    request(url)
      .pipe(fs.createWriteStream(filename))
      .on('close', callback(filename);
  };

  download(url, '../client/assets/images/' + randomizer + '.jpg', function(filename) {
    console.log('done');
    // now get model details to save
    var newLook = new Look();
    newLook.title = req.body.title;
    newLook.image = filename;
    ....
  });
```

Comment: thanks, this was good solution.  I do get an annoying 'can't set headers after they are sent' message which will try to fix.

Comment: Glad I could help. If this answers your question, then please accept it as the right answer.